# Casting string as a integer member, possible?

Tags: java, string, casting

Ok my problem isnt really a serious one, im just trying to find a clever way of access/modification of class member variables. Here is the code:

```
public class Storage{
 private int cookies= 0; 
 private int rolls= 0; 
 private int candies= 0; 
 private int lolipops= 0; 
 private int iceCreams= 0; 

 public void addCookies(int howMuch){  //this is the dirty way of creating method for
    this.cookies = cookies+howMuch;     //every member variable    
 }

 public void addValue(String stat, int howMuch){ //i would like to do it only
                                       //by passing the name
                                      //of variable and then cast it as integer
                                      //so that it would relate to my class members

    int value = this.(Integer.parseInt(stat));   //  <- YES i know its ridiculous
                                      //im just trying to explain what is my aim       
    value = value + howMuch;

    this.(Integer.parseInt(stat)) = value;
 }
}
```

Generally i would like to access a field by passing its name to a method, read value of that member, add to it some value, and then store it. Yes i know that it easily can be done with separate methods, or even with one by using some arraylist and comparisons of member names with parameter passed to method. But i would like to do it "fast" without redundant code writing.

Now i have like 5 members, but what about 15000? My aim is to simplify the whole processing and code writing. So generally is it possible to do such redundant code writing bypass? Since i know that i will always pass appropriate name to method... Unless the rule of thumb is to create method for each variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that by using reflection you can iterate through the fields/methods of your object and do your computation.

For one specific field:

```
    Field member = myObject.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    // If you know the class: Field member = MyClass.class.getField(fieldName);
    System.out.println(member.getInt(myObject)); // Get the value
            member.setInt(myObject, 4); // Set the value
```

If you want to something for all the *public* members:

```
    for(Field member: myObject.getClass().getFields())
        // Or you can do: for(Field member: myClass.class.getFields())
    {
        member.getInt(myObject)); // Get the value
        member.setInt(myObject, 4); // Set the value
    }
```

Basically, what you do is that you find the Field object that represents the members of you object, then you can manipulate it.

Comment: Ok, that seems like an overkill since there is some overhead that i initially wanted to avoid. However it is the closest solution/realization of my aim so i guess you deserve "Accepted answer".

Comment: Also, in case you have private members with getters/setters, you can also iterate over the methods to call them.

Comment: @MarianPazioch In general using reflection will be several times slower than using a keyed map.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ouch, good to know that. Thats a crucial thing. I guess then i will get back to getter/setter methods which only consume my time of writing rather than processing time & additional memory.

Comment: @MarianPazioch That's true, the reflection is pretty slow. If you have too many fields, maybe you can consider doing some scripting to generate the redundant code.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would use a collection like a Map.

```
public class Storage{
    private final Map<String, Integer> inventory = ...

    public void addCount(String key, int count) {
        Integer i = inventory.get(key);
        if (i == null) i = 0;
        inventory.put(key, i + count);
    }
```

Comment: Well this seems good, however such approach forces additional memory usage and processing that takes time, and that it the thing i want to overcome. Nonetheless, since you say that this is the normal approach to such problems so i guess most programmers in the world are sacrificing that.

Comment: Whenever you convert Strings to indexes or handle code in a generic fashion you will incur some overhead.  Usually the overhead is not enough to worry about. I would try it first and only use something more complicated if you know you have a problem.

Comment: @MarianPazioch Don't worry about performance in the first place, because it is one of the most reasons for bugs I see every day. Writing tests, writing the implementation, refactoring it to code which is nice and optimizing it to run fast should be well-separated steps in development to produce code which works.

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs will generate setters and getters for you.  This will do what you want with no bother or effort.  If this is insufficient, write a method which uses reflection to set the values.

If you have a class with 15000 members, and by this I assume you mean variables private to a class, then you have other issues to resolve.

Comment: I meant private variables of course and those 15000 was just an example. The case is not the fact that im lazy to write few more methods, i just like to optimize the code to maximum extent.  I'll look on that reflections as it seems cunning.

Comment: @MarianPazioch In general using reflection will be several times slower than using a keyed map.